# How to rerun failed scenarios in Cucumber

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, automated-tests, cucumber

I'm writting automation tests using Cucumbe in our project and plugins from our gradle dependencies, such as Junit. 
However, some scenarios are failing, mainly for timeout reasons, then rerun them would be a permanent solution.

I've tried the following code:

```
Run our test classes
@RunWith(CustomCucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        junit = "--filename-compatible-names",
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = {"stepdefinition", "main", "hooks"},
        tags = {"@MyScenario", "@5"},
        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "json:target/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                "com.github.kirlionik.cucumberallure.AllureReporter",
                "html:target/cucumber-repoIrts/cucumber-pretty",
                "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:",
                "rerun:target/rerun.txt"
        }
)

public class RunTest { }
```

**Rerun failed scenarios:**

```
@RunWith(CustomCucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        junit = "--filename-compatible-names",
        features = "@target/rerun.txt",
        glue = {"stepdefinition", "main", "hooks"},
        plugin = {
                "pretty",
                "json:target1/cucumber-reports/CucumberTestReport.json",
                "com.github.kirlionik.cucumberallure.AllureReporter",
                "junit:target1/cumcumber.xml",
                "html:target1/cucumber-repoIrts/cucumber-pretty",
                "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:",
        }
)
public class RunTestRerun {
}
```

**I see the filed been generated in the target folder, but when I try to run the rerun.txt it throws an Exception:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Neither found on file system or on classpath: Not a file or directory: C:/mytest/Signup/Client/Client.feature, No resource found for: classpath:Signup/Client/Client.feature
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.loadFromFileSystemOrClasspath(CucumberFeature.java:84)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.loadFromRerunFile(CucumberFeature.java:67)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:52)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberFeature.load(CucumberFeature.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(RuntimeOptions.java:239)
    at runner.CustomCucumber.CustomCucumber.<init>(CustomCucumber.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)

[SETUP ERROR] Neither found on file system or on classpath: Not a file or directory: C:/mytest/Signup/Client/Client.feature, No resource found for: classpath:Signup/Client/Client.feature
```

**Rerun.txt**

```
Signup/Client/Client.feature:30
```

Any thoughts on how i'd solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem while running failed test cases in eclipse. I pointed the classpath to the folder where my feature files were inside the project. You can follow below steps:

1)Right click on Project and Go to Run Configuration

2)Click on classpath

3)Select your project under User Entries and click on Advanced

4)Click on Add folders

5)Then select the folder of your project where your feature files are and then click on Apply.

Try rerunning the failed runner, it should run after this. If you go to the classpath again then you'll find the added classpath under the User Entries which the failed runner can reference to.